# Core MVC - Ajax unobtrusive does not exist

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax, nuget-package

In my Core MVC 2.2 project I added jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax (v: 3.2.6) via Nuget packages. First thing I noticed there was no local folder added for it in wwwroot/lib, also if try something simple like:

```html
@using (Ajax.BeginForm( ...
```

I get an error: CS0103 The name 'Ajax' does not exist in the current context

Please advise how to fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can obtain Unobtrusive AJAX from npm (`npm i jquery-ajax-unobtrusive` from the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio), or you can use one of the many ways that Visual Studio provides to install it from Nuget. Once you have it, you can create a new folder for it in `wwwroot\lib` and copy the file(s) there , then link the file in your `_layout` page .

You can also use LibMan , which will manage your client libraries and automatically install the libraries to destination which by default is `wwwroot\lib\YourLibrary` , you can use either GUI or use LibMan cli . Install the Libman cli:

```
dotnet tool install --global Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cli
```

To install `jquery-ajax-unobtrusive` on npm, since it's not yet on `cdnjs`, we can use `unpkg` provider and use the default location :

```
libman install -p unpkg jquery-ajax-unobtrusive
```

Another point is the markup `@using (Ajax.BeginForm( ...` **is not supported** in .Net Core  .   Instead ASP.NET Core team recommends `data-*` attributes. All the existing `@Ajax.Form` attributes are available as `data-*` attributes:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SaveForm" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST">
</form>
```

For MVC you can click [here](https://dotnetthoughts.net/jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-helpers-in-aspnet-core/) for code sample . And [here](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/unobtrusive-ajax) is the code sample for  Razor Pages version .

Comment: Thank you. I have installed it via Nuget but I do not know where the files are so to copy them to wwwroot\lib?

Comment: @TheMixy , i suggest you download  from [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/tree/master/src) , then create a new folder for it in wwwroot\lib and copy the file(s) there , or use LibMan  to install .

Answer (score 3):

Installing packages via the NuGet Package Manager in windows will install them to the .nuget location on your machine.  In the case of unobtrusive-ajax this should be something like %userprofile%.nuget\packages\microsoft.jquery.unobtrusive.ajax

This folder can then be copied to wwwroot\lib as specified in Nan Yu's answer.